# how to use extern correctly

Tags: c++, syntax

so i have 3 header file for classes
**main.cpp** includes **global.h**;**global.h** includes **lifeform.h**; **lifeform.h** includes **item.h**

i want to create an item and want to use it in **global.cpp** and **main.cpp**.i tried it like this
**extern item IronSword("weapon","Iron Sword",200,10,40);** in main.cpp or item.h or item.cpp but everytime compiler says ***[Warning] 'IronSword' initialized and declared 'extern'*** how can i use *extern* correctliy

Answer (score 0):

You try to declare *and* define the object at the same time. In the header file just do e.g.

```
extern item IronSword;  // Declare the variable IronSword
```

Then in *one* source file you have the definition:

```
item IronSword("weapon","Iron Sword",200,10,40);  // Define the variable and initialize the object
```

Comment: does it matter where i used extern after i defined IronSword